# Typescript / Konva Issues

Tags: konva

My project uses Typescript 4.9 and konva 2.1.7 (in an Angular 15 project).

I am getting type related errors such as:

```
Error: src/xyz.ts:693:22 - error TS2339: Property 'haveIntersection' does not exist on type 'Util'.



Error: src/xyz.ts:695:38 - error TS2339: Property 'nodes' does not exist on type 'Transformer'.
```

And so on. Can you please help me with what I am missing?

Thanks

EDIT: Konva worked fine until I try to use Transformer and Util. But I checked the Changelog and Transformer/Util are in v2.1.